# why else if statement is not execute without function statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, if-statement, prompt

When function is used the else if part is executed but without function the else if statement is not executed why?
here is the code which converts first character of word to  Upper Case.

```
function showName() {
    var name = prompt("Type your name");

    if (name) {
        var nameParts = name.split(' ');

        for (var i = 0; i < nameParts.length; i++) {
            nameParts[i] = nameParts[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nameParts[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
        }

        var capitalName = nameParts.join(' ');

        alert("Hello, " + capitalName);

    }
    else if (name == null){
        alert("The prompt was Canceled.");
    }
    else {
        alert("The name has not typed.")
    }
}
showName();
```

My code is working fine when function statement is used but without the function statement I'm expecting the same output when the user cancel the prompt.
Explain?

Answer (score 1):

Using global `name` variable actually sets the [window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) property. When you click cancel on the `prompt`, it returns `null` which is assigned to `name`. Any value assigned to `window.name` is converted into a string.

From [MDN - window.name:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

> Note: window.name converts all stored values to their string representations using the toString method.

So the value assigned to `name` is string `"null"`. This is why `if (name)` check evaluates to true because string `"null"` is a truthy value.

You can verify this with the following code:

```js
var name = prompt('Press cancel and check console output');
console.log(typeof name);
```

Inside a function, `name` is a local variable, so it works fine because `null` returned from `prompt` isn't stringified. As a result, `if (name)` check evaluates to false because value of `name` in this case is `null` and not the string `"null"`.

Following code verifies this:

```js
function showName() {
  var name = prompt('Press cancel and check console output');
  console.log(typeof name);
}

showName();
```